# OpenMP with Clang in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++, clang

I am trying to get access to version 4.0 of OpenMP. In order to do that I used the Visual Studio installer to get Clang, which is supposed to have support for OpenMP. However, when I try to build my program I get the following:

Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES).

These lines are what I use to get OpenMP:

```
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${MagnonPhononCMAKE} ${OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES}
```

I am new to this, but do I need to install OpenMP libraries or what is going on?